# iOS: Rotating an iPad, what stage to change view?

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, screen-rotation

My app has very different UI structures for each orientation.

At what stage in the rotation lifecycle of an iPad should I remove, then add the orientation's UI to ensure the smoothest transition?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When handling autorotation, you have 4 main methods to care about:

```
shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation

willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation                                   duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration

willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
                            duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration

didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
```

Now, the way I handle the rotation is, e.g.:

1. adjust all the frames in `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation`;
2. add/remove subviews (if needed) in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation`;
3. restore subviews (if needed) in `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation`.

More in general, I modify all properties that are animatable in `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation`; while I do all modifications that are not animatable in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation`/`didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation`.

This is what the [UIViewController reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW57) says about `willRotate`/`didRotate`:

> To temporarily turn off features that are not needed or might otherwise cause problems during the orientation change, you can override the willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration: method and perform the needed actions there. You can then override the didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation: method and use it to reenable those features once the orientation change is complete.